# Ways to quantify the (dis)similarity between spatial patterns (2D distributions + spatial autocorrelation)

Tags: distributions, correlation, spatial, biostatistics, similarities

So I have several 10000*10000 grids of the same shape & resolution, and for each grid, grid-points on this grid are discretely valued from 0 to 10 (to be more specific, the value represents the number of copies of gene X being expressed at this location (grid-point) on a biological tissue (grid)).

Now I want to quantify the similarity between two grids (i.e., two spatial distributions of values). Suppose I want to take geographical information into account rather than simply comparing the correlation between two vectors (or doing RMSDs)  that there is *spatial autocorrelation* in each grid.

My questions are:

1. Are there any statiscal methods that can take spatial information into account in comparing those 2D discrete distributions? I found something called Wasserstein metric, but that metric is originated from operations research, and it looks like the time complexity for calculation is quite high, which might not suit my large amount of grids (different genes) needed to be compared with one another.
2. If for two grids, the values in corresponding points differ significantly, while the "patterns" are similar (high regions for gene A are also high regions for gene B, vice versa), we would still consider them to be similar. I am not sure if I should use some correlation/cosine-similarity metrics in calculations, or first scale/normalize the grid. (May lead to artificial correlation?)

Thanks in advance!

More details to be found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912256/how-do-i-quantify-the-similarity-between-spatial-patterns.

Sample grid:
[image: (From SpatialLIBD package)]

Comment: With such detail available, merely summarizing the differences with a single number seems like a huge lost opportunity.  Why not perform a spatial analysis of the difference or ratio grid? In other words, select an application-appropriate measure of differences *at the level of the grid cell;* map its values; and go on from there.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comments!  Do you mean generating a new grid for each pair of original grids, where each grid cell of it has a value denoting the "difference" between corresponding grid cells on the original two grids?  This idea is quite interesting, but I think there are some issues... For example, I do not care about the actual values in corresponding grid cells, rather, I am more interested in the pattern of the grid cell values in the same grid (different gene might express in substantially different amount, while they express highly at similar locations compared to themselves).

Comment: (Continuing...) I'm not sure if there are any direct grid-cell level comparison that can deal with this. And also the expression profile is usually sparse, meaning for most grids (genes), most of the grid cells (locations) are valued 0.  I was thinking about cosine similarity, but at grid cell level I don't think cosine similarity would work (only 1 value). 
 Could you name some measures (or papers) that might be applicable? I cannot come out of a good way for now...

Comment: I found a widely-accepted normalization method, so the first issue might be resolved.  I also found this answer: stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62211/…. However, I am not sure if using the Gaussian Process method is necessary. After all, what I want is just some metrics for the similarity in order to infer the co-expression level of a pair of genes.  I need some single number because I want to build a network based on this.  Unsure how to define the "difference" grid-cell-wise.